# Angular 4/5 issue with routing Subject between Angular components via Angular Services

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular-services, subject

I have a Parent Component with an HTML click event that passes the clicked element to a method on the component.ts file, I would like this click event to be routed to Services, made into a new `Subject`, then using the `next()` method, pass the Subject to a different Sibling Component and bind the data to the Sibling Component's HTML.

So the routing of this data will look like this:

*Parent Component(via click event)* --> Service(via method on Parent Component) --> Sibling Component(via Service)*

***Here is where my data passing starts:***

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts-list',
  templateUrl: './contacts-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts-list.component.scss']
})
export class ContactsListComponent implements OnInit {

  sortedFavorites: any[] = [];
  sortedContacts: any[] = [];

  constructor (private _apiService: ApiService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){ this.getContacts()}

  getContacts() {
     this._apiService.getContacts()
     .subscribe(
       (contacts) => {

        //Sort JSON Object Alphabetically
        contacts.sort( (a, b) => {
          if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
          if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
          return 0;
        });

         //Build new Sorted Arrays
          contacts.forEach( (item) => {
           if (item.isFavorite) {
           this.sortedFavorites.push(item);
           } else {
           this.sortedContacts.push(item);
           }
         });
       });
     }

  openFavorite($event, i) {<--HTML click event passing 'i' in as object clicked
    let selectedFavorite = this.sortedFavorites[i];
      this._apiService.openSelectedContact(selectedFavorite); <--passing said object into method connected to my services.ts file 
      this.router.navigate(['/details']);
  };

}
```

The data that I am passing with the `openFavorite()` method I created is working because doing a `console.log(selectedFavorite)` logs the desired result to be passed.

***Then it comes over to services***

app.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  //API URL
  private url: string = 'assets/api/contacts.json';

  //Create new Subject and assign to local variable
  public newContactSubject = new Subject<any>();

  //Initialize HttpClient for request
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  //Pull JSON data from REST API
  getContacts(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this.url)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }


  openSelectedContact(data) {
  this.newContactSubject.next(data); <---Where data should be passing in!

  }
}
```

**Now I would like my other component to receive the data from app.service.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactsListComponent } from './app/contacts-list/contacts-list.component';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-details',
  templateUrl: './contact-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-details.component.scss']
})
export class ContactDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  selectedContact: any[] = [];

  error: string;

  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() { this.showContact() }

  showContact() {
  this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
    data => this.selectedContact = data)  <--Where the data should be showing up from services.ts file
    console.log(this.selectedContact.name);  <-- This is logging Undefined
  }
}
```

What would I be missing here? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
showContact() {
  this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
    data => {
       this.selectedContact = data;
       console.log(this.selectedContact.name);
    }
}
```

Both lines of code (including your logging) are within the function passed into the subscribe. Each time an item is emitted, it only runs the code *within* the callback function.

And as a side note ... it is normally recommended that you make your subject private and only expose it's read-only observable using code something like this:

```
private selectedMovieSource = new Subject<IMovie | null>();
selectedMovieChanges$ = this.selectedMovieSource.asObservable();
```

Notice that the subject is private and it's observable is exposed using a separate property. The components then subscribe to the public observable of the subject.

Comment: Thank you so much for this info. I have the correct object passing through my component and logging to the console from the correct Sibling Component. I am now having some issues binding the `selectedContact` to my HTML. On my html Templatle, `{{selectedContact.name}} ` should work, right? I'm not getting any errors, and the console is logging the correct thing. But it isn't *binding* to the page. Maybe this could be a separate post?

Comment: If you want to look at my HTML,here is a link to my new post asking about the HTML binding with my HTML file posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339632/angular-4-5-component-variable-from-subject-services-not-binding-to-html-templat

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your component's sort method will never sort, because you're ignoring the return value. If you wanna deal with sorting you should use like this `concatcts = contacts.sort(...)`

and i suggest you an another pattern:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactsListComponent } from './app/contacts-list/contacts-list.component';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';
import { OnDestroy } from "@angular/core";
import { ISubscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-contact-details',
    templateUrl: './contact-details.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./contact-details.component.scss']
})
export class ContactDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    selectedContact: any[] = [];

    error: string;
    private subscription: ISubscription;

    constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) { }

    ngOnInit() { 
      this.subscription = this._apiService.newContactSubject().subscribe(data => {
        this.selectedContact = data;
        console.log(this.selectedContact.name);
      });
    }

    showContact() {
      this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

But I've found have an another issue: you have defined your `selectedContact` as an *any* object array then you wanna reach the value as an object: `this.selectedContact.name` I hope you can solve this problem :)