# Angular 4/5 Component variable from Subject/Services not binding to HTML template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, binding

I have a variable in my app.component.ts file that is passed in from a controller via my services.ts file.

As far as I can see, the Object property passed to the Component via the Subject is working, because I can `console.log(this.selectedContact.name)` and It will log to the console perfectly, which would mean that it is correctly being stored into the variable `selectedContact: any;`. But I cannot seem to bind this to my HTML and I am curious as to what I may be missing.

Here is my app.component.ts file for the view I'm attempting to bind to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactsListComponent } from '../contacts-list/contacts-list.component';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact-details',
  templateUrl: './contact-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact-details.component.scss']
})
export class ContactDetailsComponent  implements OnInit {

  selectedContact: any;

  constructor(private _apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() { this.showContact()}

  showContact() {
    this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
      contact => {
         this.selectedContact = contact;
         console.log(this.selectedContact.name);
      });
  }
}
```

Here is my HTML file (The view I am attempting to bind to.:

```
<div id= 'contact-card' >
  <header>
  <button routerLink='/home'>< Contacts</button>
  </header>
  <section id= card-container>
    <img id ="largeContactPhoto" onerror="onerror=null;src='../assets/User Large/User — Large.png';"
         src={{selectedContact.largeImageURL}} />
    <h1> {{selectedContact.name}} </h1>
    <h2> {{selectedContact.companyName}} </h2>
    <ul>
      <hr>
      <li class="contact-data">
        <h3> Phone: </h3>
        {{selectedContact.phone.home}}
      <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="contact-data">
        <h3> Phone: </h3>
        {{selectedContact.phone.mobile}}
      <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="contact-data">
        <h3> Phone: </h3>
        {{selectedContact.phone.work}}
      <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="contact-data">
        <h3> Address: </h3>
        {{selectedContact.address.street}}<br>
        {{selectedContact.address.city}},{{selectedContact.address.state}} {{selectedContact.address.zipcode}}
      <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="contact-data">
        <h3> Birthdate: </h3>
        {{selectedContact.birthdate}}
      <hr>
      </li>
      <li class="contact-data">
        <h3> Email: </h3>
        {{selectedContact.email}}
      <hr>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</div>
```

app.service.ts (where the click event data is being passed to app.component.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

  //API URL
  private url: string = 'assets/api/contacts.json';

  public newContactSubject = new Subject<any>();

  //Initialize HttpClient for request
  constructor(private _http: Http) { }

  //Pull JSON data from REST API
  getContacts(): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.get(this.url)
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }
  openSelectedContact(data) {
  this.newContactSubject.next(data);

  }
}
```

Sibling Component **THIS IS WHERE THE CLICK EVENT HAPPENS*** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contacts-list',
  templateUrl: './contacts-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contacts-list.component.scss']
})
export class ContactsListComponent implements OnInit {
  title : string = 'Contacts';
  sortedFavorites: any[] = [];
  sortedContacts: any[] = [];
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor (private _apiService: ApiService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(){ this.getContacts()}

  getContacts() {
     this._apiService.getContacts()
     .subscribe(
       (contacts) => {

        //Sort JSON Object Alphabetically
        contacts.sort((a , b) => {
          if (a.name > b.name) {return 1};
          if (a.name < b.name) {return -1};
          return 0;
        })

         //Build new Sorted Arrays
          contacts.forEach( (item) => {
           if (item.isFavorite) {
           this.sortedFavorites.push(item);
           } else {
           this.sortedContacts.push(item);
           }
         });
       });
     }

  openFavorite($event, i) { <--Click event coming in from HTML template
    let selectedFavorite = this.sortedFavorites[i];
      this._apiService.openSelectedContact(selectedFavorite); <--Routing this data to services.ts file
      this.router.navigate(['/details']); <--Navigate to detailed view to see selected contact.
  };

}
```

This binding will work with any other test variables that i put into my app.component.ts file and they get bounded to the page. I feel like this is the right syntax for it to be properly binding the object.properties, but it doesn't seem to be working.

What might I be missing on this? Thanks a lot in advance!!

EDIT One: I feel like I should also add that this exact same code *was* working before when I had my  component routed to this component. It was only when I moved my  files to a new component and created a different new  that this started happening. Maybe it is isn’t imported correctly somewhere?

***EDIT TWO***: I have refactored the code in the original post and corrected my TypeScript declarations and removed `this` from my html template. I have placed my `console.log(this.selectedContact.name)` function inside my `showContact()` method and it does log the correct name once the name in the contacts list is clicked along side this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'largeImageURL' of undefined`. So it is logging `this.selectedContact.name` correctly and that variable isn't defined anywhere else in my application. I have added my app.service.ts file as well as my sibling component.ts file just to put this in context where the click event happens. I want the click event data to go from Sibling component --> Api Service.ts file --> Sibling component on a click event. This is very confusing to me why this isn't happening.

***EDIT THREE***
One other issue that I have noticed is that whenever I attempt to use the safe navigation operator to resolve this, my highlighting changes in my html template, making me think that it is breaking it.

[image]

versus this:

[image]

Notice the change in the `</h1`> highlighting? This has subsiquently made *every* open and closing tag show up in grey instead of the red now. I have never attempted to use the safe navigation operator, so I am unsure as to whether this is normal. I have tried it with different spacing around the `{{` and `}}` and still no luck.

Comment: why are you using `this` keyword in data Interpolation?

Comment: It was my attempt to be slightly more thorough. It still does not work without the `this` keyword

Comment: It appears that `selectedContact` is an array but you are using it like an object

Comment: Are you getting any JS errors showing up in your console?

Comment: @Daniel W Strimpel The only one i get is `TypeError: Cannot read property 'home' of undefined in my html file but when I console.log the same thing `console.log(selectedContact.phone.home` It shows up perfectly in the console. It's just not binding.

Comment: When are you console logging that? When the component is initially ran you do not have the necessary properties on your `selectedContact` (which is typed incorrectly btw). Use the `?.` syntax to let angular know that the property immediately preceding may be null (i.e. `selectedContact?.phone?.home`)

Comment: I'm logging it inside of the showContact method right after the data passed in is assigned to the variable `showContact() {
    this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe(
      data => {
         this.selectedContact = data; console.log(this.selectedContact.name); <--Here
      }
  }`

Comment: Could you revised your code in your question to show what you have now? As others have said ... you don't use *this* in the template. Also, your declaration for the `selectedContact` was incorrect. After making those two changes, you still have no error in the console and no data?

Comment: @DeborahK Original Post has been updated.

Comment: Just to be clear ... in *CODE* you need the *this* to reference any of your component's properties. In the *TEMPLATE* you don't use the *this*. It is implied to be the component's properties and methods.

Comment: Okay, that definitely makes sense and makes me feel less crazy :-)...original post is being refactored again

Comment: At this point, it may be easiest for us to help you if you post a stackblitz demonstrating your issues. stackblitz.com

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help on this @DeborahK (and everyone else!), it is much appreciated. This is just a frustrating issue that I can't wrap my head around, so thanks for your patience. I will attempt to get it up and running on stackblitz.com and post a link to it here.

Answer (score 2):

Are you expecting an array or an object? You should type exactly what you are getting from your service. 
Here you mention an array:

```
selectedContact: any[] = [];
```

Here you mention an object.

```
<h1> {{this.selectedContact.name}} </h1>
```

Give a shot in your template with the `json` pipe.

```
{{ selectedContact | json }}
```

This will help you debug.

Also, because your data is displayed on the browser before it is received by your service, you will get an undefined variable. Either use `?` or an `*ngIf`. (With the *ngIf, don't define your selectedContact as an array to start with)

```
<div id= 'contact-card' *ngIf="selectedContact">
```

or

```
<h1> {{this.selectedContact?.name}} </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am expecting an object. I have changed `selectedContact: any[] = [];` to `selectedContact: <any>{};` and I it is still not working. I have attempted to add `*ngIf= "selectedContact"` to my container and it comes up completely blank...which would mean it isn't getting to the Container....but it IS logging to the console from the Component. Very strange.

Comment: Where is your console.log() ? The syntax should be: `selectedContact: any;`. The last reason why this wouldn't work would be that you have another JavaScript error.

Comment: The console.log() is inside the showContact() method that is called inside of ngOnInit(). `showContact() { this._apiService.newContactSubject.subscribe( data => { this.selectedContact = data; console.log(this.selectedContact.name); <--Here } }`. And this logs the correct name. It's just not being pushed to my `selectedContact` variable. I did change it to `selectedContact: any;` but I am still getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: When everything fails like this, delete the whole template. Then do `{{ selectedContact | json }}` inside of it. You will see if you get something. As for the ? breaking your editor, then your editor is not good. It's a valid syntax. If you use the ?, you have to use it EVERYWHERE where you use selectedContact.

Comment: I have completely deleted everything and I have just one `{{ selectedContact | json }}` and nothing shows in the view at all. Which would make me think there is an issue with the object not even making it to the component via services. But it is *still*  logging `this.selectedContact.name` to the console correctly from the local variable `selectedContact = any;`.